# Out of memory problem with zlib

Tags: c++, zlib

I want to compress a string using zlib. If I put this function in a loop after about an hour "compress" returns -4 which means Z_MEM_ERROR. Anybody knows where is the problem?

```
std::string compressData(std::string const& line)
{

    char *src=(char*)line.c_str();
    int srcLen=strlen(src);

    int destLen=compressBound(srcLen);
    char *dest=new char[destLen];

    int result=compress((unsigned char *)dest ,(uLongf*)&destLen ,(const unsigned char *)src ,srcLen );

    QByteArray sd = QByteArray::fromRawData(dest, destLen);
    QString hexZipData (sd.toHex());
    std::string hexZipDataStr = hexZipData.toStdString();

    if( result != Z_OK)
    {
       hexZipDataStr = "";
       std::cout << "error !"; 
    }

    delete []dest;
    dest = NULL;

    return hexZipDataStr;
}
```

Comment: `char *src=(char*)line.c_str();` -> Don't do this. c_str() returns a pointer-to-const-char, so you are casting away constness. If you would have used C++-casts (static_cast<> in this case) the compiler would have been able to warn you. (though this is prolly not the reason for your problem)

Comment: can you post a minimal, complete example? I guess qt is superfluous here.

Comment: Again: Use C++ casts. Possibly, you converting incompatible pointers e.g. in `(uLongf*)&destLen` <-- Why don't you declare destLen as uLongf?

Answer (score 0):

The only suspicious place I can see is that you supply your `int destLen` as an output parameter of type `uLongf`.  This may blow up your stack if `uLongf` is larger than `int`, and the "long" part suggests it could be so on 64-bit platforms.

I would recommend you to declare `destLen` of type `uLongf` right away and avoid the cast.

Other than that I cannot se any problems with your code.